# Usergroup tracking with application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, user-tracking

We want to run our queries to get the pageviews, exceptions, etc against not only against the users themself, but also against usergroups. This will help us prioritize future development.

So my question is if it's possible to add an usergroup or even better some sort of tags to the user that we can use to query over.

I know we can do this by creating all the custom calls, but is there a default way? If not, what is the best way to add those parameters to the custom calls? At the moment I’m using the javscript function appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext() to pass the user information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add the user group or tags using custom properties in any/all events you send.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics

```
telemetryClient.TrackEvent( "the event", 
   new Dictionary<string,string> { {"UserGroup", theUserGroup } } );
```

etc.

Once you get that working the way you want, you can then use telelmetry initializers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties

and create an initializer to create and set those custom properties on *all* telemetry sent from the application, instead of only sending it in calls you wrote explicitly like above.

*Edit to add*: Also, if you set this information up using custom dimensions, you can now use it in filters in the new usage tools that were announced at //build 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-segmentation

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to query not just requests but also pageviews, exceptions, etc against usergroups, you should definitely go with `TelemetryInitializers`. Telemetry initializers allow you to add global properties to all your telemetry data which means they are executed for all telemetry events that are sent from your app.

The below example shows how to add a `TelemetryInitializer` to add UserGroup or any other property for every telemetry event. The example assumes that a group identification for a user can be obtained from their list of claims. However it could also be as simple as a role. You could also tweak it and implement your own way of identifying the user's group. Here we are grouping on the basis of the user's Tenant which is obtained from the list of Azure AD claims for the user. Once this is done you should be able to query as well as create charts for your requests, exceptions, pageviews etc using the `UserGroup` property that will be available in each of them.

```
public class UserGroupTelemetryIntitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Retrieve the claim that helps identify the user's group. In this case
            // we retrieve the Tenant ID from the Azure Active Directory claims
            var user = (context.User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal);
            var userGroup = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid");

            // Add the Value of the claim as the UserGroup property for each telemetry
            if (userGroup != null)
                telemetry.Context.Properties["UserGroup"] = userGroup.Value;
        }
        else
            telemetry.Context.Properties["UserGroup"] = "None";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to load your telemetry initializer, using `ApplicationInsights.config`:

```
<ApplicationInsights>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <!-- Fully qualified type name, assembly name: -->
    <Add Type="MvcWebApp.Telemetry.UserGroupTelemetryIntitializer, MvcWebApp"/>
    ...
  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Alternatively, you could also load the initializer using code *instead*. In your `global.asax.cs` or `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers
        .Add(new UserGroupTelemetryIntitializer());
}
```

You can read more about Telemetry Initializers [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling.md#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer).